# Ruby: How can i make a combobox that shows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, combobox

i want to know how to make a commbobox that shows a list of all users in my database, let me explain myself:

I have two clases:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :password, presence: true, confirmation: {strict: true}
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
  validates :telephone, uniqueness: true, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }, presence: true, length: { minimum: 9, maximum: 9 }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 4, maximum: 30 }, format: { with: /^[\w\s-]*/u, multiline: true,
                                                                                  message: 'only allows letters' }
  has_many :valorations
end

class Valoration < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :points, presence:true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: 100 }
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :hability
end
```

And i have a show create view for the validation class:

```
 <%= form_for(@valoration) do |f| %>
  ...errors check...
  <div class="field">
    #combo box code to be added
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And what i wanna do is to create a combo box that does something like the following pseudocode using fselect:

Invented code:

```
<%= f.select :user_id, options_for_select( for_each user do |u|
   [[u.name,u.id]] 
end %>
```

So at the end i have an combobox with all the users, i'm a noob to rails really know how to do it so any help is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below to achieve what you want.

```
<%= f.select :user_id, User.all.collect { |u| [ u.name, u.id ] } %>
```

For more info, you can refer to this [**link**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select)